# SQL Server pivot without grouping

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table similar to below:

```
Machine Status  Value  
MJ02    I       0.05  
MJ02    K       0.1294  
MJ02    K       0.0775  
MJ02    F       0.2844  
MJ02    K       0.1093  
MJ06    I       0.05  
MJ06    K       0.2832  
MJ06    J       0.0753  
MJ06    F       0.0919  
MJ06    K       0.0891
```

I want the data to be in below format:

```
Machine  I        K      J       F       K  
MJ02    0.05    0.2069  0       0.2844  0.1093  
MJ06    0.05    0.2832  0.0753  0.0919  0.0891
```

I have tried to use pivot , but it is grouping all the status .But I want to group only those statuses which are same and are consecutive for same machine like 2nd and 3rd row in the sample data. If the same status is repeating again after some different status(like 5th row with status K), I want to show it as a separate column.

Can anyone help me in achieving this.Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: An SQL result set should never have two columns with the *same* name as you apparently want. So you shouldn't expect SQL to be able to produce the results you're asking for. (Also, what you're asking for would require a query that can return a *varying* number of columns, depending on the data, which is also not something you can achieve with a normal query)

Comment: how do you defined `consecutive` ? based on which column ? is there another column in the table that define the sequence or ordering ?

Comment: by status column

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I understand that 2 columns shouldn't have same column name.But our requirement urges us to prepare the data as mentioned above.